# else & elif statements seems that is not working in Python

Tags: python

I'm traying to make a simple rock paper scissors game but it seems that the `if` and `elif` statement do not respond.  It only `print`s the `else` statement.

Here's the code:

```
from random import randint

rock = '''
    _______
---'   ____)
      (_____)
      (_____)
      (____)
---.__(___)
'''

paper = '''
    _______
---'   ____)____
          ______)
          _______)
         _______)
---.__________)
'''

scissors = '''
    _______
---'   ____)____
          ______)
       __________)
      (____)
---.__(___)
'''
t = [rock, paper, scissors]

player = int(input("choose 0 for rock and 1 for paper and 2 for scissors \n"))
cpu = t[randint(0,2)]

print(t[player])
print(cpu)  

if player == 0 and cpu == 2:
  print("YOU WIN")

elif cpu == 0 and player == 2:
  print("YOU LOSt")

elif player == 1 and cpu == 0:
  print("you win")

elif cpu == 1 and player == 0:
  print(" YOU LOST")

else:
  print("this is invalid input! ")
```

Comment: `cpu` can *never* be equal to any of the integers you're comparing it to - it's a string!

Comment: More whitespace does not equal better readability: all these empty lines stretch out your code and make it vastly *less* readable.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want `cpu = randint(0,2)` so that it's just the int. Then later when you need the string, replace `cpu` with `t[cpu]`

Answer (score 0):

change this line `cpu = t[randint(0,2)]` to this `cpu = randint(0,2)`

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

As others mentioned, you need to change the two lines to:

```py
cpu = randint(0,2)
print(t[player])
print(t[cpu])
```

By the way, there is a simple way to determine the outcome without if-statements:

```py
from random import randint

rock = '''
    _______
---'   ____)
      (_____)
      (_____)
      (____)
---.__(___)
'''

paper = '''
    _______
---'   ____)____
          ______)
          _______)
         _______)
---.__________)
'''

scissors = '''
    _______
---'   ____)____
          ______)
       __________)
      (____)
---.__(___)
'''

outcome = ["DRAW", "YOU LOST", "YOU WON"]
t = [rock, paper, scissors]

player = int(input("choose 0 for rock and 1 for paper and 2 for scissors \n"))
cpu = randint(0, 2)
result = (cpu - player) % 3

print(t[player])
print(t[cpu])  
print(outcome[result])
```